# How to filter elements based on XPATH?

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want to select span element following only top countries or only other countries

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span class="hb">Top Countries</span>
  </div>
  <span>Australia</span>
  <span>Guinea-Bissau</span>
  <div>
    <span class="hb">Other</span>
  </div>
  <span>Austria</span>
  <span>Mauritania</span>
  <span>Mauritius</span>
  <span>Nauru</span>
  <span>Palau</span>
  <span>Saudi Arabia</span>
</div>
```

I have tried with `//*[text()='Top Countries']/../following-sibling::span and not(//*[text()='Other']/../following-sibling::span)`

If I try both XPATH separately they work, but in combination, they do not work.

**I want to select only top countries and get them in a list**: `['Australia', 'Guinea-Bissau']` and filter out the other countries.

If I use `//*[text()='Top Countries']/../following-sibling::span`all countries are getting selected. ie. `['Australia', 'Guinea-Bissau', 'Spain', 'Switzerland', 'UK', 'USA', 'Austria','Mauritania', 'Mauritius','Nauru','Palau','Saudi Arabia']`

With `//*[text()='Other']/../following-sibling::span` item selected are `['Austria','Mauritania', 'Mauritius','Nauru','Palau','Saudi Arabia']`

The list is generated dynamically so I can't select them based on text/country name.

Comment: please clarify, what are you trying to do?  If each xpath works separately, and you only want to get one or the other, then just use the separate xpaths.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware added clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is:

```
//span[preceding-sibling::div[1]/descendant::text()='Top Countries']
```

This selects:

```
Element='<span>Australia</span>'
Element='<span>Guinea-Bissau</span>'
```

---

Obviously, to select only the **other countries**:

```
//span[preceding-sibling::div[1]/descendant::text()='Other']
```

---

See the wonderful [**online xpath tester**](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).

Comment: Thanks for promt reply, ```//span[text() = 'Top Countries']/../following-sibling::span``` selects all elements i want to select only ['Australia', 'Guinea-Bissau']

Comment: Thanks @Jan. Little explanation why I chose this answer or opted to get elements this way. The list is very dynamic, cases here, Either top or other will be present, both will be present, neither will be present. If I don't go with Jan's locators,  I'll end up with nested if else and list manipulation. With these locators just two checks and no list manipulation at all.

Comment: @pr4bh4sh: Gald to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Assuming there are always **two countries** under **Top countries**.

```
//span[text() = 'Top Countries']/../following-sibling::span[1]
//span[text() = 'Top Countries']/../following-sibling::span[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two lists, one with all the elements and one with the unwanted elements

```
List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='Top Countries']/../following-sibling::span"));
List<WebElement> other = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[text()='Other']/../following-sibling::span"));
```

And than remove the `other` countries

```
all.removeAll(other);
```

`all` will now contain only "Top Countries"